# Javascript sees number as string on calculating interest rate

Tags: javascript

I've created a small application to fill in a amount of dollars, and the choice wich interest rate you want on it.

This looks like this:

```
function calculation() {
    var money = document.getElementById('money').value;
    var interest = document.getElementById('interest').value;
    
    var sum = money + (money / 100 * interest);
  
    document.getElementbyId('sum').innerHTML = sum;
}
```

For my HTML, it looks like this:

```
<input id="money" type="number" min="1" max="1000000" onchange="calculation()">

<input id="interest" type="number" min="0" max="100" value="10" step="0.1" onchange="calculation()">%

<h2 id="sum"></h2>
```

I have tried to add the `Number` method to my sum like this:

```
var sum = Number(money + (money / 100 * interest));
```

But that didnt work.

**Input in the amount of money**

> 100.00

**Input in the amount of interest**

> 10

**Expected output**

> 110

**Actual output**

> 10010

How do i make it so that it will actually sum up the amount of dollars plus the interest rate?

Comment: JS sees the things correctly, `input.value` is always a string. Convert as early as possible, i.e. `var money = +(document.getElementById('money').value);`

Comment: Try `Number(money) + (...)`

Comment: @Teemu Ah thanks, didnt even know that.

Comment: @Michelle Aye' that worked, but there should be another way right then using `Number(....)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript's parsefloat method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

```
function calculation() {
    var money = parseFloat(document.getElementById('money').value);
    var interest = parseFloat(document.getElementById('interest').value);

    var sum = money + (money / 100 * interest);

    console.log(sum);
}
```

Or if you want to stick with `Number`

```
function calculation() {
        var money = Number(document.getElementById('money').value);
        var interest = Nynber(document.getElementById('interest').value);

        var sum = money + (money / 100 * interest);

        console.log(sum);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, what does this do exactly then? The same as `Number`?

Comment: It parses the `string` and converts it into a floating point number. So parseFloat("10") would return 10.0. It solves your problem because you were converting the strings to Numbers *after* the string manipulations were done. So by doing it earlier the correct numerical operations are performed. If you'd like you could still use Number() in place of parseFloat above

Comment: Or if you are only dealing with integers you can use parseInt to avoid having decimals.

Comment: Hmm, could you provide me with a jsFiddle please? it still occurs the problem when im using toFixed(2)

Comment: How are you trying to use toFixed(2) ?  I don't see it anywhere in your code. But the difference between parseFloat / Int and Number is that the former will return a `number` literal . Where the latter will return a `Number` primitive wrapping object. But I do not have time to make a fiddle. I have tested my answers and they work on my end. The toFixed(2) problem seems like a different question, because it isn't in the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

You're converting the string to a number after performing String concatenation on the amount and the interest, when you need to convert the amount to a number and then add the interest to it. So you want:

```
var sum = Number(money) + (money / 100 * interest);
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, using `.value` returns a String, so you need to use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` when assigning `money` and `interest`.

Otherwise it will perform string concatenation on use of `+`.

Based on what you want for your inputs, you'll want to change your javascript to:

```
function calculation() {
  var money = parseFloat(document.getElementById('money').value);
  var interest = parseInt(document.getElementById('interest').value);

  var sum = money + (money / 100 * interest);

  document.getElementbyId('sum').innerHTML = sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the values immediately.

Even when you do this:

```
var sum = Number(money + (money / 100 * interest));
```

The order of operators will evaluate what's inside `()` first, so you are still adding a string to a number inside `()`.

There are lots of different ways to convert string to number so here's one that simply does it by multiplying by one:

```
var money = 1 * document.getElementById('money').value;
var interest = 1 * document.getElementById('interest').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use parseInt() or parseFloat() functions.